# Azure internal DNS search suffixes

Tags: powershell, azure, internal-dns

I mainly use Azure for IaaS purposes (Linux and Windows VM's).
We have a strict Front-End (FE) / Back-end (BE) segregation policy.

FE and BE are in the same Virtual Network, but in different Subnets/Cloud Services.

I've noticed that FE and BE VM's are getting different DNS suffixes via DHCP:

- FE machines get frontend-something.***a9***.internal.cloudapp.net as DNS search suffix
- BE machines get backend-something.***a1***.internal.cloudapp.net as DNS search suffix

FE machines can reach each other simply by hostname thanks to this search suffix but ***can't*** reach BE machines unless I add the BE DNS search suffix in their config.

My question is:
Is there a way (via PowerShell / Azure CLI) to find out what DNS suffix is used in a subnet/Cloud Service ?

I need this to automate deployments and I can't predict what the internal DNS search suffix will be (like the "a9" and "a1" that I don't control and that appear in the DNS search suffixed examples above).

Kind Regards,

O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Get-AzureVM with -Debug you can look in the XML for InternalDnsSuffix.  However, if you use ARM-based deployments, all VMs in the VNET get the same suffix.

Regards
Gareth